# Texture Paint edge smothness

Tags: texture-painting, brushes

The left line of the image is drawn with the smother falloff settings and the right one with sharper but the transition from with to black is nearly the same only the size changes. How can I get the brush edge to bemore like a gradient?
Thanks for helping

[image]

Comment: You have to adjust the falloff. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/sculpt_paint/brush/falloff.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the Fallowvalue really low helped

[image]